# Cannot Display an Image in Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

When I run the program the canvas shows up but the Image does not.

```
canvas = Canvas(frame, width = 128, height = 128, bg= 'white')
    image_data = Image.open('NoArt.gif')
    ppm_f = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_data)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = ppm_f, anchor = NW)
    canvas.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

any Ideas??

PS.

I have 
PIL ver 1.6,
python 2.6, and
The Version of Tkinter that comes with python 2.6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I figured It out. Apparently due to the way that python deals with garbage disposal the pictures just get erased. A reference to the image in the global scope is required. This is the working code I eventually ended up using:

```
self.photo = PhotoImage(file="noart.ppm")
    self.Artwork = Label(self.frame, image=self.photo)
    self.Artwork.photo = self.photo
    self.Artwork.pack()
```

that `self.Artwork.photo = self.photo` is the important part. It ensures that the Image will be shown.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in [this very answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3366046/7032856) and [this more popular question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16424091/7032856) and also in [effbot.page](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)

> When you add a PhotoImage or other Image object to a Tkinter widget,
>   you must keep your own reference to the image object. If you don’t,
>   the image won’t always show up.
>
> The problem is that the Tkinter/Tk interface doesn’t handle references
>   to Image objects properly; the Tk widget will hold a reference to the
>   internal object, but Tkinter does not. When Python’s garbage collector
>   discards the Tkinter object, Tkinter tells Tk to release the image.
>   But since the image is in use by a widget, Tk doesn’t destroy it. Not
>   completely. It just blanks the image, making it completely
>   transparent…
>
> The solution is to make sure to keep a reference to the Tkinter
>   object,

For example the `image` in below code [image: won’t always show up], if at all as it isn't declared in global scope:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def show_image():
    img_label = tk.Label(root)
    image = tk.PhotoImage(file="test.png")
    img_label['image'] = image

    img_label.pack()


show_image()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

whereas in the example below `img_label.image` is declared globally, as an attribute attached to our very `img_label` in this example, and [image: will be shown]:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def show_image():
    img_label = tk.Label(root)
    img_label.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="test.png")
    img_label['image'] = img_label.image

    img_label.pack()


show_image()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

It is though still strange as `img_label` isn't globally declared either. A less confusing way would be adding `global image` as the first line to the `show_image`.

Comment: Good answer, but posted on a bad question (it doesn't even have a MCVE). Would you mind posting your answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)? That's the question I usually use as a duplicate target, and I think your answer would be a valuable addition there.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else ever has a similar problem, you can try this hardcoded solution:

```
import Image
import Tkinter as tk

def cleanhex(x):
    return str(hex(x))[-2:]

def renderimage(target,data,w,h):
    canvas = tk.Canvas(target,width=w,height=h)
    canvas.pack()
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            c = "#" + cleanhex(data[x,y][0]) + cleanhex(data[x,y][1]) + cleanhex(data[x,y][2])
            canvas.create_line(x,y,x+1,y+1,fill=c)

im = Image.open("whatever.whatever")
renderimage(root,im.load(),im.size[0],im.size[1])
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you're doing?

Comment: Loading an image and drawing it pixel by pixel. This is probably not something you should use in practice (there are other more optimized functions that exist in Tkinter), but it works.