# Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This code works:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './test.gif')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo)
root.mainloop()
```

It shows me the image.

Now, this code compiles but it doesn't show me the image, and I don't know why, because it's the same code, in a class:

```
import tkinter

class Test:
    def __init__(self, master):
        canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master)
        canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './test.gif')
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo)

root = tkinter.Tk()
test = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: http://effbot.org is down. The gist of it is that the image is passed by reference. If the reference is to a local variable, the memory referenced gets reused and the reference becomes stale.
The variable storing the image should be in the same scope (has to have the same lifetime) as the Tk gui object it appears on.

Comment: @maszoka: `effbot.org` may be down, but you can still read the link [Why do my Tkinter images not appear?](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111190625id_/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) thanks to the Internet Archive [wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/web.php).

Comment: Also note that the same problem can appear anywhere temporary `PhotoImage`s are used, for example in a calling sequence such as `label = Label(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(data)))`.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The variable `photo` is a local variable which gets garbage collected after the class is instantiated. The solution involves saving a reference to the photo, for example:

```
self.photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(...)
```

If you do a Google search on "tkinter image doesn't display", the first result is this:

[Why do my Tkinter images not appear?](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111190625id_/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)

Comment: Wow. Do they consider this a bug in tkinter? They should.

Comment: I found a very old ticket, already closed without a fix: https://bugs.python.org/issue632323

Comment: The link is not working atm, is there another way than using "global"?

Comment: @aru: This example shows how to do it without using a global.

Comment: @Aru: FYI, I just fixed the broken link.

Comment: @TamasHegedus: I agree it's bug, but apparently not one that anyone has ever bothered to fix after (currently) nearly two decades. Have lost count how many times I see a question regarding to it still pops up.

Comment: Anyhow, feels weird that `effbot` says that `tkinter` widget keeps reference to the internal object because I do not think that we can retrieve back the `ImageTk` object that they said is referenced by a widget.

Comment: Do you have to use this approach if your class is a subclass of PhotoImage? Do you still need to save the PhotoImage?

Comment: @Enderman: a reference needs to be kept by something, somewhere.

Comment: But won’t it be saved as self in the class?

Comment: @Enderman: no, because it's referencing itself. An object needs an external reference to it or the garbage collector might destroy it.

Comment: Umm so should I save the PhotoImage.__init__() function as a variable? Does that even work and would that save the PhotoImage correctly?

Comment: @Enderman: no. You need to save a reference to the instance of the class.

Comment: Ah. Thanks @BryanOakley! Appreciate the help! (I am not a professional coder yet lol)

Comment: Why wouldn't *the canvas object* maintain a reference to the image, in the same way that the master Tk instance is maintaining a reference to the canvas (which is *also* a local within `__init__` here)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: because the canvas object exists inside the embedded tcl interpreter. The tcl interpreter doesn't know anything about python objects. Similarly, python doesn't know that the embedded tcl interpreter has a reference to the image.

Comment: I mean, in terms of tcl's internal structure, how come its internal representation of the window has some kind of reference to the canvas, but the canvas doesn't have any kind of reference to the image? Or are we saying that Python GCing its `PhotoImage` object is incorrectly telling tcl to free the memory for its own internal representation of the image? In that case, why doesn't it crash with a dangling pointer?

Answer (score 10):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

def open_img():
    global img
    path = r"C:\.....\\"
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    panel = Label(root, image=img)
    panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")
but1 = Button(root, text="click to get the image", command=open_img)
but1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

> Just add global to the img definition and it will work

Comment: This answer is fine for a program that just uses functions, but if, as in the OP's case, you use a class, than `global` is _not_ the way to go.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is Python automatically deletes the references to the variable by a process known as [Garbage Collection](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-does-garbage-collection-work-in-Python). The solution is to save the reference or to create a new reference.

The following are the ways:

1. Using `self` to increase the reference count and to save the reference.

```
import tkinter

class Test:
    def __init__(self, master):
        canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master)
        canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './test.gif') # Changes here
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo) # Changes here

root = tkinter.Tk()
test = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

2. Saving it to a list to increase the reference count and to save the reference.

```
import tkinter
l=[]
class Test:

    def __init__(self, master):
        canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master)
        canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './test.gif')
        l.append(photo)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo)

root = tkinter.Tk()
test = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

While using method 2, you can either make a global list as i did or use list inside the class. Both would work.

Some useful links:

- [About Garbage Collection 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-does-garbage-collection-work-in-Python)
- [About Garbage Collection 2 (*More useful*)](https://towardsdatascience.com/memory-management-and-garbage-collection-in-python-c1cb51d1612c)

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, **whenever you create your image in an indented block of code you need to safe a reference to that image**. This is because of the python's automated [**garbage collection**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52619031/13629335) and it collects everything with a refcount of 0 when it destroys/leaves that frame/page/indented block of code.

---

The **canonical way** to deal with it is to **have a list of images somewhere in the global namespace** and add your image-references to that list. This is convenient but not very efficient and should be used for small applications.

```py
import tkinter as tk

global_image_list = []
global_image_list.append(tk.PhotoImage(file = 'test.png'))
```

An **more efficient way** is to **bound an attribute to your widget or class** that holds that reference for you, as Bryan proposed in his answer. It doesn't make a difference if you do `self.image` or `widget.image` that was assigned `widget = tk.Widget(..` before. But this also might not the right approach if you want to use that image further even when the widget is destroyed and garbage collected.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text='test')
label.image = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'test.png')
label.configure(image=label.image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `global photo` as the first line inside the function.

Comment: And then you create a 2nd `Test` instance and the first instance loses its image. Congratulations.

Comment: There is definitely no no need to use `global` when in a class. `self.` takes care of all of that.