# Avoiding garbage collection for Tkinter PhotoImage (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-photoimage

I'm using MacOS v 12.6 and Python v 3.9.6. Why does the code below garbage collect the image unless the commented-out line is uncommented? Isn't using `self.img` supposed to be enough to avoid garbage collection?

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np

class Meter:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.pos, self.img = (None,) * 2
        k = np.empty((300,300,3), dtype=np.uint8)
        k[:,:] = (10,) * 3
        img = Image.fromarray(k, "RGB")
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.label = Label(self.root, image=self.img)
        # self.label.foo = self.img
        self.label.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Meter(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I've used `ImageTk` several times and for some reason am having problems avoiding garbage collection this time. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193976/13597979), which directed me to add the commented-out line, and it solved my problem. But like the answerer, I don't know why. The comments for this answer didn't clarify the issue, and the answer is quite old, so I am asking here.

Comment: `self.img` is indeed keeping a reference to the image in your `Meter` instance - but you're not keeping a reference to that instance, so it all gets garbage-collected anyway.  Something like `meter = Meter(root)` would fix that.  `self.label.foo` works differently because Tkinter itself is preserving references to widgets you create.  (It can't do the same for images, because that would be potential megabytes of memory leaks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't using self.img supposed to be enough to avoid garbage collection?

It is, except that `self` refers to an instance of `Meter` and you're not keeping a reference to the instance of `Meter`. So, the garbage collector thinks you're done with the instance of `Meter` and tries to free up memory.

If you save an instance, then `self.img` inside `Meter` will be enough:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    meter = Meter(root)
    #^^^^^^^
    root.mainloop()
```