# TKinter button won't work if inside function

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I have this code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        
        self.mainloop()
```

I want to add button with image to it

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file="close.png")
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Click me!", image=img, compound="right")
        button.config(image=img)
        button.pack()
        self.mainloop()
```

[Properly working button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Uwh5.png)

And that works as intended
But when i try to move this button inside a class method, it wont show any image

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.closeButton()
        self.mainloop()  
    def closeButton(self):
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file="close.png") 
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Click me!", image=img, compound="right")
        button.config(image=img)
        button.pack()
```

[Improperly working button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2qSR.png)

I already tried changing the way i load images to using PIL, but nothing changed.
I also tried making another class just for button, but this works worse than when its in function.

Can someone explaing to me why its happening, and maybe suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PhotoImage` object is created inside the `closeButton` method and is therefore garbage collected after the function has run. See the comment under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193976/13525512).

Create your image object while initializing `Window`:

```py
class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.close_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="close.png") 
        self.closeButton()
        self.mainloop()
    def closeButton(self):
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Click me!", image=self.close_img, compound="right")
        button.pack()
```