# Simple Image viewer

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am new to this site, and I am trying to create a simple image viewer in Python 2.7 using Tkinter, But when I try to load an image in it,it does not show anything!, I bet it is something embarassingly obvious, but I dont know what's wrong. I am using Windows XP. Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk(className="Image viewer")

canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 600
root.config(bg="white")

def openimage():
    picfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=picfile)
    canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=img) 

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

xscrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)
button = Button(root,text="Open",command=openimage)
button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
canvas.pack(side=TOP)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
xscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

mainloop()
```

Update: It works when i remove the file browser, and give it the path to a file, but i want the file browser, and using a label works, but scroll bars dont work with it, and i want to be able to scroll the picture.

Comment: I have to say, for being new to the site this is a pretty fantastic question - you've given us what you wanted to happen, what happened instead, and the code that seems to have failed. Keep up with that and you will go far.

Comment: try with a .gif and then a .jpg. Tell us what happens.

Comment: I tryed a .jpg, a .png, and a .gif

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Display an Image in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359717/cannot-display-an-image-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found on "[The Tkinter PhotoImage Class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)" that PhotoImage can't be assigned to local variable in function because garbage collector remove it.

So you can use global variable:

```
img = None

def openimage():
    global img

    picfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=picfile)
    canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=img)
```

or assign image to existing widget (for example `canvas`)

```
def openimage():
    picfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    canvas.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=picfile)
    canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=canvas.img)
```

*by the way*: you should check if file was selected

```
def openimage():
    picfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if picfile:
        canvas.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=picfile)
        canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=canvas.img)
```

add `scrollregion` and you have file viewer with working scrollbars

```
def openimage():
    picfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if picfile:
        canvas.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=picfile)
        canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=canvas.img) 
        canvas.configure(canvas, scrollregion=(0,0,canvas.img.width(),canvas.img.height()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know about problem in your code but You can use this function in place of your one:

```
def openimage():
    try:
        Artwork.destroy()
    except Exception:
        pass
    picfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=picfile)
    #canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=img)
    Artwork=Label(root,image=img)
    Artwork.img=img
    Artwork.pack(side=BOTTOM)#do packing urself
```

**Note that is is the minimal implementation.**

Comment: Yeah, i already tried using a label as a canvas, but it doesnt support scrollbars

Comment: Well you didnt mentioned that :P