# How to make an image to appear on tkinter.Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a 'Game' class,  which has to create a window with image, here's the code that I've tried, but the image does not appear. The directory there exists
and no errors are produced

```
from tkinter import *
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title('          ')
        self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=800, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.bg = \
        PhotoImage('C:\\Users\\iv4um\\ninjafight\\hj\\officelight.gif')
        self.bgimage = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.bg, \
        anchor='nw')
        self.tk.update()
```

I expect the image to be at the screen, but all I get is blank screen, with no image. Image is 800 * 600 pixels and it's a .gif.

Comment: Have you checked [Tkinter GIF not display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594217/tkinter-gif-not-display)? Both links in the accepted answer should help, depending on your problem.

Comment: Try `self.bg = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\iv4um\\ninjafight\\hj\\officelight.gif')`

Comment: this is more useful than the answers

Comment: @AndriiChumakov Thanks. Didn't feel complex enough for an offical answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try using the pillow module (PIL, python imaging library), you should use this to handle gifs as images...

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to use Tkinter module, you can look [Play an animated gif in python with tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770847/play-an-animated-gif-in-python-with-tkinter). Although, the answer uses Label in order to display the gif.

I suggest that you could try [pyglet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/) module it is more easy.

```
import pyglet

# giphy directory
giphy_file = "giphy.gif"

# make an animation object
animation = pyglet.resource.animation(giphy_file)

sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)

# create a window
win = pyglet.window.Window(width=sprite.width, height=sprite.height)

# background color = r, g, b, alpha of the window
green = 0, 1, 0, 1
pyglet.gl.glClearColor(*green)

@win.event
def on_draw():
     win.clear()
     sprite.draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: the question is about tkinter.Canvas and not about tkinter.Label or pyglet.

Comment: @AndriiChumakov yes of course. I suggest something else. I cannot help you with Canvas.