# How to load an image into a python 3.4 tkinter window?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, tkinter

I've spent some time looking online and so far haven't found anything that answers this without using PIL, which i can't get to work is there another way to do this simply?

Comment: Are you using PIL or [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/)?

Comment: what means `i can't get to work` ? Do you can't install ? Do you get error message ? image disappears (very common problem) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Display an Image in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359717/cannot-display-an-image-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tkinter has a [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20200723031040/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) class which can be used to display GIF images. If you want other formats (other than the rather outdated PGM/PPM formats) you'll need to use something like PIL or Pillow.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(file="myfile.gif")
label = tk.Label(image=image)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

It's important to note that if you move this code into a function, you may have problems. The above code works because it runs in the global scope. With a function the image object may get garbage-collected when the function exits, which will cause the label to appear blank.

There's an easy workaround (save a persistent reference to the image object), but the point of the above code is to show the simplest code possible.

For more information see this web page: [Why do my Tkinter images not appear?](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111190625/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)

Comment: Thank you this is great, problem was my college wont let extra python modules such as PIL or Pillow to be installed on the system. :)

Comment: Sorry, when I tried it in my program it only shows a blank square where I would expect to see the image, so it must open the image as the dimensions are correct but it isn't displaying what is in the image?

Comment: Found the adding a line, label.image = image, made the image appear as it kept a reference. This works with .png files too.

Comment: The links are not functional. Kindly update.

Comment: @Zia: thanks for alerting me. I've fixed the links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIL library which available for python 3.
First, you need to install PIL using this command (using pip):
`pip install pillow`
then:

```
`from tkinter import *`
```

`from PIL import Image, ImageTk`

```
`class Window(Frame):`

    `def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        load = Image.open("parrot.jpg")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)`
```

Answer (score -2):

Luke, this is too late , however may help others. Your image has to be in the same sub directory with .py script. You can also type  './imageFileName.png'

Comment: This is not true - the image can be anywhere in your filesystem. You just need to give a correct path to the file.