# How to fix this syntax error with the while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make it so that when you close the tinker GUI another one opens and this process repeats

I have tried this while command but it says invalid syntax.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file="scary.png")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()

while 2 > 1
```

Comment: Refer my solution below for image issue and also infinite times of opening your tkinter window @PorkBurrito

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for infinite times opening the tkinter window:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("scary.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

while True:
    root = Tk()
    label = Label(root, image=photo)
    label.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**
I've added code for opening image of any format in Tkinter, for that you have to install the required package with `pip install pillow` (PIL package)

I've tested it without image, it is working. Hope it helps !

Answer (score -1):

You were missing the loop body.
Now it has but since 2 > 1 is always true it's an infinite loop.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file="scary.png")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()

while 2 > 1:
  pass
```

Comment: that doesnt make it open the image again tho

Comment: You have invalid syntax in your snippet and this answer addresses it. Opening an image is another issue that you can raise in another question.

Comment: @PorkBurrito for images, you refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024118/how-to-load-an-image-into-a-python-3-4-tkinter-window

Comment: This will simply cause the program to freeze after the first window is destroyed.

Comment: @BryanOakley What else would you expect for a 2 > 1 condition in this while loop? Plus did explicitly say that in the answer that it only addresses the syntax error which is exactly what OP asked for.