# Image working in one button but not another

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter, root

When I use this code to execute an image inside a button within a frame it works just fine:

```
image2= PhotoImage(file="questionmark.gif")
f3buttonQ=Button(f3,image=image2, command = findcustomer).place(x=425,y=10)
```

However, when I just want to use this in the root frame I use this code:

```
image2= PhotoImage(file="questionmark.gif")
f3buttonQ=Button(root, image=image2,command = findcustomer).place(x=450,y=110)
```

The image doesn't load in the latter piece of code and the only difference between the two would be the f3 in the first one. Thanks.

Update:

So I managed to get the command to work by using this:

```
photo2= tk.PhotoImage(file="questionmark.gif")
button = Button(image=photo2,command = findcustomer).place(x=450,y=110)
```

When I run this alone the image is loaded just perfectly onto the button, but when I add this line under it they both go blank again and the image isn't loaded:

```
f3findProduct=Button(image=photo2, command = findproduct).place(x=110,y=190)
```

Comment: I would recommend providing a full test case so we can see what is going on

Comment: My guess is that in the second one the reference to image2 is not kept, according to [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#images) : _When the last Python reference to the image object is deleted, the image data is deleted as well._

Comment: I tried calling the image again as a new name, such as photo3 and then running the second button command but also seemed to cause them both to load empty. Do I need a duplicate copy of the image but save it with a different name and call each individual picture of each button?

Comment: @LHez, if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would be very helpful for answering this question, is the code you provided in the global scope or in a function?

Comment: It was in a function but the question has been answered. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Display an Image in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359717/cannot-display-an-image-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short story is that your image is garbage collected and is no longer displayed. You must keep a reference of it.

**from [effbot](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm):**

> When you add a PhotoImage or other Image object to a Tkinter widget, you must keep your own reference to the image object. If you don’t,
>   the image won’t always show up.
>
> The problem is that the Tkinter/Tk interface doesn’t handle references
>   to Image objects properly; the Tk widget will hold a reference to the
>   internal object, but Tkinter does not. When Python’s garbage collector
>   discards the Tkinter object, Tkinter tells Tk to release the image.
>   But since the image is in use by a widget, Tk doesn’t destroy it. Not
>   completely. It just blanks the image, making it completely
>   transparent…
>
> The solution is to make sure to keep a reference to the Tkinter
>   object, for example by attaching it to a widget attribute:

```
photo = PhotoImage(...)

label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()
```

You must do that for each image you need to display

Comment: The tkinter interface is very much handling the images correctly as using pythons garbage collection is the intended behaviour according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#images) : _When the last Python reference to the image object is deleted, the image data is deleted as well,_