# Why does place method give me an error when used on an object in Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run this code(part of a larger project):

```
def Initialize (event,tk):
    event.delete("all")
    parch = tk.PhotoImage(file = "Parchment.png" )
    parchment = event.create_image(175, 25, image = parch, anchor = "nw")
    parchment.place(175, 25)`
```

Which gives the error:

```
parchment.place(175, 25)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'place'
```

Technically, it all works fine and does its job; but having error messages is not really good either way.

Comment: Apparently `parchment` is a number, which doesn't have a `place` method. Check the docs to see what `create_image` returns. Are you sure the method doesn't just mutate `parch`? In that case, change it to `parch.place(175, 25)`.

Comment: `create_image` and other `create_*` don't create widgets but objects on canvas which don't have methods `place()`/`grid()`/ `pack()` because they don't need them (because they are not widgets).

Comment: I understand they don't need those methods, nonetheless without those methods the desired image just does not show up

Comment: @Salad Your image probably doesn't show up because it lacks a global reference. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3359717/7032856). Or you can simply make `parchment.image = parch`.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but it's no good, I guess I'll just find a workaround, or solve it a later date.

Comment: I'd try `event.parch_img = parch`.

Comment: @nae you are a genius sir, although the solution is much simpler, I figured it out thanks to you. I merely had to globalise the variable which declared which file would be used for the image.

Comment: It's very strange that you have a parameter named `event` which is a canvas rather than an event object. It makes your code hard to understand.

Comment: yes, i know. its a habit to use it. And here I mainly wanted something easy to remember for me so I could use it without having to think too hard about it

Comment: @Salad - please DO NOT include answer into the question - feel free to post solution as an actual answer if you want to (I rolled back your edit that adds solution). Side note: this question is [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361267/why-are-complete-question-deviation-making-answers-effectively-meaningless-is) which may bring additional attention to the post.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_image.html), the `create_image` method returns the *integer ID number* of the image object it creates.
All the canvas object creation methods return such an ID.

You can use [canvas methods](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) to interact with the objects given their ID (e.g. move them using the `.move` method).

Comment: I think the question above this needs a roll-back edit, for this answer to be more related.

Comment: The stuff after the edit on how the image is "lost" is a completely different question, really.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I [tried suggesting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361267/7032856) the previous edit. But apparently, it's not exactly the same as roll-back and was judged as if I was the one changing the question.