# Image files using gif

Tags: python, tkinter

The following program will not run because the file 'python.gif' is not recognised.

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title( 'Image Example' )
img = PhotoImage( file = 'python.gif' )
label = Label( window , image = img , bg = 'yellow' )
small_img = PhotoImage.subsample( img, x = 2, y = 2 )
btn = Button( window, image = small_img )
txt = text( window, width = 25, height = 7 )
txt.image_create( '1.0', image = small_img )
txt.insert( '1.1' , 'Python Fun!' )
can = Canvas( window , width = 100 , height = 100 , bg = 'cyan' )
can.create_image( ( 50, 50 ),  image = small_img )
can.create_line( 0 , 0 , 100 , 100, width = 25 , fill = 'yellow' )
label.pack( side = TOP)
btn.pack( side = LEFT, padx  = 10 )
txt.pack( side = LEFT )
can.pack( side = LEFT, padx = 10 )
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: put some effort into formatting the question...

Comment: i  suggested him the edit about format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play an Animated GIF in python with tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770847/play-an-animated-gif-in-python-with-tkinter)

Comment: Is `python.gif` really a GIF image?  May be it is a JPEG image with .gif extension, so `tkinter.PhotoImage` cannot recognise the format.

Comment: Please show the actual error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter doesn't automatically show animated gifs. You will have to do the animation yourself by loading each frame in a loop.

See [Play Animations in GIF with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518072/play-animations-in-gif-with-tkinter)

If your problem is that you're not seeing any image at all, it's probably due to the image being garbage-collected.

See [Cannot Display an Image in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359717/cannot-display-an-image-in-tkinter)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\agard\Documents\Documents\MyCode\image.py", line 4, in <module>
    img = PhotoImage( file = 'python.gif' )
  File "C:\Users\agard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3393, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\agard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3349, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "python.gif"
>>> ERROR